# Without user loging inner page is disable wordpress

Tags: login

how to set without user loging inner pages is disable or display message please loging Frist

**Ex.** I want if user not loging and open abouts us page and display message please loging Frist and don't see any countain. When user login click on about us page see all countain

Comment: Your question is not clear and as per the assumption you need to check the content of a page depending upon the user logging. You can do so by using **[is_user_logged_in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)** and if this not what you are looking for, then please add a substantial amount of information regarding the same

Comment: Ex. I want if user not loging and open abouts us page and display message please loging Frist and don't see any countain. When user login click on about us page see all countain

Comment: This is something you can find easily by making a search in the codex or in the community here. Please do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function

```
    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //load your page here
    } else{
      echo ("Please <a href=".wp_login_url().">Login</a> First");
    }?>
```

Comment: your ans is right but i have tomany template when i use this code add in all pages. if any solution like i add some code in my project

Comment: You can use that code in your header.php file. It will automatically load in your every pages.

Comment: I got the Answer its easy by css..

main div(.lor1) means comman div start after header and finesh before footer
Add new class (.lor1.kun) in main div when user loging this main class display: block;
make new html Ex. display mess loging frist one (.lor1.user_not_login)                                           ` <?php     
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
 ?> 
 <style>
    .lor1{ display:none;}
 .lor1.kun{ display: block;}
 .lor1.user_not_login{ display: block;}
 </style>
 <?php
  }  ?>
`